# Meaning of node in dojo.connect (node, onclick, callback)

Tags: javascript, exception, dojo, event-binding

I am trying to pass a flag variable into node where it verify if flag is true then execute dojo.connect (flag, onclick, callback). Other its skip a callback function.

Comment: Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and reformat your question. I looks like not research efforts has been made before posting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node is the DOM object representation of each element that composes HTML, basically.

Take a look in the offical Dojo Toolkit's documentation to it's feature:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/connect.html

You haven't specified but i suppose you're using Dojo in it's 1.6, it's an old practice since we have AMD architecture implemented in it's structural funcionalities, You must have something like this:

```
// Saving your handle
var handle = dojo.connect(node, "onclick", callback);
// Removing the handle
dojo.disconnect(handle);
```

When you use `dojo.connect(flag, onclick, callback)` we presume you have an element, a DOM-node (in this case the 'flag').

In Dojo 1.6 versions or older you can take a node by it's ID like: (Some offical docs: https://dojotoolkit.org/api/#dojo.byId)

```
// Here's your node (by ID)   
var my_node = dojo.byId("foo");
```

Hope it helps on your understanding.

Do you need something like this?

```
// Your custom callback
function your_callback_function() {
  // You business rules, in this case:
  if (dojo.query('#your_flag:checked')) {
    // Do something..
  }
}

// binding event to the DOM-node and callback 
var handle = dojo.connect(dojo.byID("your_flag"), "onclick", your_callback_function);
```

You can see a bit more about < 1.6 versions Dojo Events's features in: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/index.html#events

I suggest you to know more about AMD and Dojo's new features since it's changes.

Comment: Yes I have set default flag value to false , But I want to execute when flag is true. That is
dojo.connect(if(flag) is true , onclick,myFunctionName)
execute myFunctionname when it is true

Comment: Updated my answer, please tell me if it's what you want. I'm centralizing business rules into the callback, here's your intelligence. Let me know if it works. Take a look: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/query.html#better-and-faster-dojo-query

Comment: this is helpful instead of inline function in example i want to redirect to custom function which is located in another java script file.

Comment: You can set a function outside of the connect and set it to the callback argument in it. I've updated my answer, hope this could help you in your need. You can see too a lot of tutorials about connect and events in dojo in this link: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/quickstart/events.html#quickstart-events